# Retrieve long text in android through php

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, httprequest

I have a long text (dimension of a book) stored in an MySQL database online, that I have to download in an android app through a PHP webserver.

This is the JSON parser I use (part of it comes from [this tutorial](https://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/)):

```
public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {}

// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method, List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // check for request method
        if(method == "POST"){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method == "GET"){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 10000000);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }
    Log.i("json", "here");
    Log.i("json", json + "   ,   ");
    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

    }
}
```

If I try to return it in one call it gives this error:

> E/JSON Parser: Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of

I think it is due to the dimension of the file so I tried to break down the calls retrieving for example 1000 characters at the time (which if tested on the PHP file alone on a browser works). This is my code of the async task that retrives the book:

```
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

        boolean suc = false;

        // Check for success tag
        int success;
        try {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> parametri = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            parametri.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_BOOKID, Integer.toString(id)));

            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                    url_book_file_length, "GET", parametri);

            // check your log for json response
            Log.d("Single Book length", json.toString());

            // json success tag
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
                // successfully received product details
                JSONArray productObj = json
                        .getJSONArray(TAG_BOOK); // JSON Array

                // get first product object from JSON Array
                JSONObject jbook = productObj.getJSONObject(0);

                int length = jbook.getInt(TAG_LENGTH);
                int current = 1;
                String file = "";
                suc = true;

                while (current <= length){
                    parametri = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    parametri.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_BOOKID, Integer.toString(id)));
                    parametri.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_START, Integer.toString(current)));

                    if (length-current>=LENGTH_MAX){
                        parametri.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_LENGTH, Integer.toString(LENGTH_MAX)));
                        current+= LENGTH_MAX;
                    } else {
                        parametri.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_LENGTH, Integer.toString(length-current+1)));
                        current = length+1;
                    }

                    json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                            url_book_file, "GET", parametri);

                    // check your log for json response
                    Log.d("Single Book pezzo file", "current " + Integer.toString(current) + "   " + json.toString());

                    // json success tag
                    success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                    if (success == 1) {
                        // successfully received product details
                        productObj = json
                                .getJSONArray(TAG_BOOK); // JSON Array

                        // get first product object from JSON Array
                        jbook = productObj.getJSONObject(0);

                        file += jbook.getString(TAG_FILE);

                    }else{
                        suc = false;
                        break;
                        // product with pid not found
                    }
                }

                book.setFile(file);
                Log.i("File", "saved");


            }else{


                // product with pid not found
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return suc;
    }
```

And this is the PHP file:

```
<?php

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// check for post data
if ((isset($_GET["bookid"]))&&(isset($_GET["start"]))&&(isset($_GET["length"]))) {
    $start = $_GET['start'];
    $length = $_GET['length'];
    $bookid = $_GET['bookid'];

    // get a book from books table
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT SUBSTRING(file, $start, $length) AS file FROM book WHERE bookid = $bookid");

    if (!empty($result)) {
        // check for empty result
        if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

            $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);

            $book = array();
            $book["file"] = $result["file"];

            // success
            $response["success"] = 1;

            // user node
            $response["book"] = array();

            array_push($response["book"], $book);

            // echoing JSON response
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // no book found
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "No book found";

            // echo no users JSON
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    } else {
        // no book found
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "No book found";

        // echo no users JSON
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    //echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

However now, for example when LENGTH_MAX is 1000 only some of the calls are successful (in particular the first 8 and then some random ones) and the other return the same error as before.

The webserver is stored in a 1and1 hosting service, might it be due to a limit set by them on the server calls? Is it due a bug in my code? What other method to retrieve the text would you suggest me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `method == "POST"`  ... that's how we compare string in java by androidhive hehehe

Comment: @GC Apps Lab remove this line in PHP file  **echoing JSON response**

Comment: @RatilalChopda yeah, sorry it was part of the comments in the code but it looked on a new like in Stack

Comment: @GCAppsLab please check in manifest file add **<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />** and also check in your device internet is connected or not.

Comment: @RatilalChopda Yes it is there, moreover otherwise the first 8 blocks and the length wouldn't be retrieved